# UIButton - How to set Minimum Font Size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, font-size

My question is simple. Is there any way to set a minimum font size for `UIButton` like this can be easily set up with `UILabel`?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
button.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
button.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping;
```

copied from [Set minimum font size UIButton with margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006067/set-minimum-font-size-uibutton-with-margin)

Comment: While it worked for the author, there is no minimum font size setting provided in the answer

Comment: @PrzemysławWrzesiński: `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;` does that

Comment: No, it does not. It shrinks text, but to set minimum font size you also need to use minimumScaleFactor

Comment: @PrzemysławWrzesiński: UILabel or UIButton??

Comment: UILabel: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilabel/1620544-minimumscalefactor

Answer (score 16):

Anoop's answer works like a charm. You can also do this in IB using User Defined Runtime Attributes:
- choose Button in IB
- Add Attribute
- KeyPath: titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth
- Type: Boolean
- Value: true
[Screenshot from IB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4ITT.png)

Answer (score 3):

Set Minimumfontsize is not available in iOS8 use minimumscalefactor instead.

Answer (score 2):

in Swift 4/5

Please make sure that yourBtn is available in @IBoutLet, not in action
    in viewdidLoad or viewWillAppear

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    yourBtn.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 1
    yourBtn.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    yourBtn.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byClipping
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 5.0

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        YourButton.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 1
        YourButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Teetz's answer works like a charm. In case if you want to add margin between titleLabel of **UIButton** edges after it ***adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth***, you can add few spaces before first character & after last character. So, that it looks neat.